# Passing Anonymous Parameters into Oracle using ODP.net

Tags: parameters, odp.net

Somehow or the other, I learned that I can simply pass in parameters into an Oracle stored proc and it would be able to convert the parameters into the appropriate type.  Well I am running into issues dealing with that.  I am getting an "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement" returned to me...  I am guessing it is because I am attempting to pass in strings...  That is what I read somewhere anyway... 
"http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00900_invalid_sql_statement.htm"

What is the technique for inputing Oracle parameters into a stored proc and then executing that stored proc using .net Variables?  Will I have to convert the .net strings into ODP data types?  I hope not...

Here is what my code generall does...

```
    XmlAttribute xAttribute;
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ACODBConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sProc, conn))
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (string path in paths)
                {
                    string OracleParam;
                    xAttribute = AcoXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//dataTemplateSpecification/templates/template/elements/element[@name='{0}']", path)).Attributes["value"];
                    if ((xAttribute.Value == null))
                    {
                        OracleParam = "";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(colName[i], OracleParam);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        OracleParam = xAttribute.Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(colName[i], OracleParam);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                conn.Open();
                outcome = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I am pulling the values out of an XML document so naturally the values are going to be strings... It is going to suck so much a$$ if I have to figure out how to change the strings into the appropriate data type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmd.Parameters.Add() expects an object that is a parameter (not the value of the parameter)

so this is doable, with a few caveats but here is a test case:

---

set up the Oracle bit:

```
create table testParam(aa number, bb varchar2(50) , cc date) 
/
create or replace procedure testProcParam(
                  p_aa IN TESTPARAM.AA%TYPE , --usage of tableName.ColumnName%Type has this "scoped" to the table.column AA (here it is number)
                  p_BB IN TESTPARAM.BB%TYPE , --The usage of TYPE here has it defined as VARCHAR2
                  p_CC IN TESTPARAM.CC%TYPE  --this is DATE
) is
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testParam (AA, BB, CC) VALUES(P_AA, P_BB, P_CC);
END testProcParam ;
/
```

---

now for the .net bit:

```
  OracleConnection con = Connect(constr);

  // Set the command
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("testProcParam", con);
  cmd.CommandType   = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.BindByName = false; /*mark this false to bind by position*/

  string AA = "123456" ;
  OracleParameter oparamAA  = new OracleParameter() ;
  oparamAA.Value = AA;
  cmd.Parameters.Add(oparamAA);

  string BB = "abcdefghijklmnopqrst" ;
  OracleParameter oparamBB  = new OracleParameter() ;
  oparamBB.Value = BB;      
  cmd.Parameters.Add(oparamBB);

  string CC = "01-AUG-11" ; /*we rely on the nls date parameter to 'cast' this*/
  OracleParameter oparamCC  = new OracleParameter() ;
  oparamCC.Value = CC;      
  cmd.Parameters.Add(oparamCC);      

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();

  con.Close();
  con.Dispose();
```

Now things to take note of:

1. Notice how I create the parameter and assign the "string" value to it (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleParameterClass.htm#i1011127 you will see that the constructors are either no dbtype or you must explicitly state it, this gets around that)
2. if the parameters are not named (ie you are relying on ordinal position) you must "cmd.BindByName = false;"
3. For dates, the NLS format comes into play here (thus you are opening yourself up to date issues if you change date formats etc)

---

then you will have your data:

```
SELECT * FROM testParam;

AA                     BB                                                 CC                        
---------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------------------- 
123456                 abcdefghijklmnopqrst                               01/08/11 00:00:00  

/* --now to clean up
DROP procedure testProcParam ;
DROP table testParam ;
*/
```

---

---

**EDIT**

Per your comment; in the parameters in PL/SQL when you use

> tableName.ColumnName%Type

you are actually just tying that datatype to the column's data type in the table (this allows the column to be changed and it won't break the package).

for the example I provided:

```
                  p_aa IN TESTPARAM.AA%TYPE , 
                  p_BB IN TESTPARAM.BB%TYPE , 
                  p_CC IN TESTPARAM.CC%TYPE
```

is the same as

```
                  p_aa IN NUMBER, 
                  p_BB IN VARCHAR2  , 
                  p_CC IN DATE
```

Not sure of an 'anonymous/generic datatype' that you can pass in

Comment: Wow.  Now that is a master full answer to a question...  Thanks for the help.  I guess what I was missing ,among other things, is setting the bind by name parameter to false...  I will test it out.  Probably some time this afternoon (got a ton of stuff to do today).

Comment: @DmainEvent terrific, let me know if you encounter any problems

Comment: Hey, I am having a hard time getting the date time into the right format.  How would you recommend one go about that...  I get the date as a string and DateTime.Parse(string, "DD-MM-YYYY); and then to string that DateTime... Does that sound about right?  If you have any advice I would definitely appreciate it.  THanks.

Comment: @DmainEvent I figured the date would be a sticky point.  it depends on the [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm) [among other things](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:351017764854).  I guess formatting it to the nls_date_format would work, but that will leave you open to that changing and whatnot (or if you know it is a date, just build the param as a dbtype date and go from there to avoid those pitfalls!)

Comment: I do infact know that some of them are indeed dates... I will write something up and pass in dbtype dates...

Comment: OK question,  Just looking over you code again, it seems as though the stored proc has to be designed in such a way that it can except anonymous types.  I wish I had designed it myself, unfortunately I did not and I am positive it is not designed that way.  I am guessing you can't add anonymous parameters if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @DmainEvent, I have added a description to the parameters I passed in.  there is no anon. type (that I know of!) that can be passed in, the param in the table.column%type just ties the param type to the column type in the table.

Comment: @Harrison I realize this is an older post, but I am wondering if you could expound a bit on building "the param as a dbtype date"  Is setting dbType = dateTime enough to get past NLS_DATE_FORMAT Issues?  I posted a related question too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372909/mvc-using-odp-net-getting-ora-01840