# MVC using ODP.NET getting ORA-01840

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, plsql

I am writing a simple MVC Application using ODP.NET.  I am trying to call a Pl/Sql proc that inserts a record.

Here is the simple Pl/Sql:

```
procedure spAddCountry(pGisRecid in country.GISRECID%type,
                     pCountryCode in country.COUNTRYCODE%type,
                     pCountryName in country.COUNTRYNAME%type,
                     pCurrencyCode in country.CURRENCYCODE%type,
                     pEUTerritory in country.EUTERRITORY%type,
                     pFatCAStatus  in country.FATCASTATUS%type,
                     pFATF in country.FATF%type,
                     pFSCountryCode in country.COUNTRYCODE%type,
                     pInsertedBy in country.INSERTEDBY%type,
                     pInsertedOn in country.INSERTEDON%type,
                     pLanguages in country.LANGUAGES%type,
                     pNCCT in country.NCCT%type) is
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
  INSERT INTO COUNTRY (GISRECID, COUNTRYCODE, COUNTRYNAME, CURRENCYCODE, 
         EUTERRITORY, FATCASTATUS, FATF, FSCOUNTRYCODE, INSERTEDBY, 
         INSERTEDON, LANGUAGES, NCCT)
  VALUES(pGISRECID, pCOUNTRYCODE, pCOUNTRYNAME, pCURRENCYCODE, 
         pEUTERRITORY, pFATCASTATUS, pFATF, pFSCOUNTRYCODE, pINSERTEDBY, 
         pINSERTEDON, pLANGUAGES, pNCCT);
  Commit;
end;
```

I am having difficulty passing the **date** parameter, **pInsertedOn**, to the Stored Proc.  I have verified that the web form retrieves the form data successfully and calls the AddCountry method below, which in turns calls the stored proc, spAddCountry, after populating all of the parms.

Here is a snippet of the MVC C# code.

I get the following exception: **"ORA-01840 input value not long enough for date format".**

```
        public void AddCountry(Country aCountry)  //because the country object field names match the form field names they automatically get bound!!
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=XYZ;User Id=XYZ;Password=xyz;";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "tstpack.spAddCountry";  
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ...
            OracleParameter paramInsertedBy = new OracleParameter();
            paramInsertedBy.ParameterName = "pInsertedBy";
            paramInsertedBy.Value = aCountry.InsertedBy;  //aCountry.InsertedBy is a string
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramInsertedBy);

//            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");  //flail...
            OracleParameter paramInsertedOn = new OracleParameter();
            paramInsertedOn.ParameterName = "pInsertedOn";
//            paramInsertedOn.Value = DateTime.Now;  //just testing to see if it's WebForm issue
//            paramInsertedOn.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString(), ci);  //flail!
            paramInsertedOn.Value = aCountry.InsertedOn;  //aCountry.InsertedOn is a DateTime
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramInsertedOn);      
            ...
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //CRASH!  ORA-01840    
            conn.Close();    
            }
```

Just to verify that the flow of the program is working, I tried removing the date parm "pInsertedOn" from the pl/sql and from the parm list above, and everything worked fine.  I know I am going off of the rails with the date.  Can someone tell me how to pass a date to Oracle from an MVC WebForm?  Is there some sort of type cast needed?  I would really appreciate an example too.

Thanks so much!

*ps, I did try changing the parm type to Varchar2 in the Pl/Sql and doing some conversions myself in the Pl/Sql, the automatic MVC binder was getting in my way, forcing the property of **paramInsertedOn.OracleType** to **DateTime**.  I tried forcing it to Varchar2, but no luck there either...*

Comment: What's the datatype declaration of `InsertedOn` property in `Country` class? And what's the datatype of `INSERTEDON` table column in `country` table?

Comment: I think you're on the money trying to convert it to VARCHAR2. Try this: change the parameter binding to VARCHAR2 (or String or whatever), then convert the DateTime to string in a known format (e.g. 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' or whatever). Change the matching parameter in `spAddCountry` to VARCHAR2, then use the TO_DATE function to convert the parameter to DATE when inserting it, e.g. `..., TO_DATE(pInsertedOn, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), ...` - just be sure  the date format in the TO_DATE call matches up with how the DateTime was converted to String in `AddCountry`. Best of luck.

Comment: @DennisR InsertedOn in the Country Class is DateTime.  InsertedOn in the Country Table is DATE.

Comment: @DennisR your question made me think about the what's going on under the hood.  I see that Params' OracleDBType is being automagically set to 'TIMESTAMP' as soon as Value is set.  This made me think to set OracleDBType to 'DATE' (after setting the value so it doesn't get squashed).  Unfortunately same error. :(

Comment: can you post the definition of the table and what the [date time] string looks like that you are passing into oracle {for instance '20140820'}?